# Need help on Xpath Expression

Tags: xml, xpath

Need some help on Xpath expression. I have the following xml:

```
<ldaConfigTblV4_0>
<Value>
  <LDA_CONFIG_T_V4>
    <CONFIG_ATTRB_VALUE>90</CONFIG_ATTRB_VALUE>
    <BOX_LABEL>
      <Value>   
        <TIEGROUP>1</TIEGROUP>
        <LABEL_TEMPLATE>LABEL_TEMPLATE</LABEL_TEMPLATE>
        <GTINTYPE>TEST GTINTYPE</GTINTYPE>
        <GTINVALUE>1</GTINVALUE>
        <MODELNUM>TEST MODELNUM</MODELNUM>
        <MODELDESCRIPTION>TEST MODELDESC</MODELDESCRIPTION>
        <COLOR>TEST Color</COLOR>
        <COUNTRY>TEST COUNTRY</COUNTRY>       
      </Value>        
    </BOX_LABEL>
    <TIEGROUP>1</TIEGROUP>
    <TIEGROUPIsNull>false</TIEGROUPIsNull>
    <CONFIG_ATTRB_NAME>LOB</CONFIG_ATTRB_NAME>
    <WO_ID>20015670070</WO_ID>
    <WO_IDIsNull>false</WO_IDIsNull>
    <WORK_ORDER_LINE_NO>1</WORK_ORDER_LINE_NO>
    <WORK_ORDER_LINE_NOIsNull>false</WORK_ORDER_LINE_NOIsNull>
    <SYSTEM_LABEL>
      <Value>
        <TIEGROUP>1</TIEGROUP>
        <LABEL_TEMPLATE>LABEL_TEMPLATE</LABEL_TEMPLATE>
        <GTINTYPE>TEST GTINTYPE</GTINTYPE>
        <GTINVALUE />
        <MODELNUM>TEST MODELNUM</MODELNUM>
        <MODELDESCRIPTION>TEST MODELDESC</MODELDESCRIPTION>
        <COLOR>TEST Color</COLOR>
        <COUNTRY>TEST COUNTRY</COUNTRY>           
      </Value>        
    </SYSTEM_LABEL>
    <SALES_ORDER_REF>10016041740</SALES_ORDER_REF>
    <SALES_ORDER_REFIsNull>false</SALES_ORDER_REFIsNull>
  </LDA_CONFIG_T_V4>
  <LDA_CONFIG_T_V4>
    <CONFIG_ATTRB_VALUE>91</CONFIG_ATTRB_VALUE>
    <BOX_LABEL>
      <Value>
        <TIEGROUP>2</TIEGROUP>
        <LABEL_TEMPLATE>LABEL_TEMPLATE_2</LABEL_TEMPLATE>
        <GTINTYPE>TEST GTINTYPE_2</GTINTYPE>
         <GTINVALUE>2</GTINVALUE>
        <MODELNUM>TEST MODELNUM_2</MODELNUM>
        <MODELDESCRIPTION>TEST MODELDESC_2</MODELDESCRIPTION>
        <COLOR>TEST Color_2</COLOR>
        <COUNTRY>TEST COUNTRY_2</COUNTRY>
      </Value>        
    </BOX_LABEL>
    <TIEGROUP>2</TIEGROUP>
    <TIEGROUPIsNull>false</TIEGROUPIsNull>
    <CONFIG_ATTRB_NAME>LOB</CONFIG_ATTRB_NAME>
    <WO_ID>20015670070</WO_ID>
    <WO_IDIsNull>false</WO_IDIsNull>
    <WORK_ORDER_LINE_NO>2</WORK_ORDER_LINE_NO>
    <WORK_ORDER_LINE_NOIsNull>false</WORK_ORDER_LINE_NOIsNull>
    <SYSTEM_LABEL>
      <Value>
        <TIEGROUP>2</TIEGROUP>
        <LABEL_TEMPLATE>LABEL_TEMPLATE_2</LABEL_TEMPLATE>
        <GTINTYPE>TEST GTINTYPE_2</GTINTYPE>
        <GTINVALUE />
        <MODELNUM>TEST MODELNUM_2</MODELNUM>
        <MODELDESCRIPTION>TEST MODELDESC_2</MODELDESCRIPTION>
        <COLOR>TEST Color_2</COLOR>
        <COUNTRY>TEST COUNTRY_2</COUNTRY>
      </Value>        
    </SYSTEM_LABEL>
    <SALES_ORDER_REF>10016041740</SALES_ORDER_REF>
    <SALES_ORDER_REFIsNull>false</SALES_ORDER_REFIsNull>
  </LDA_CONFIG_T_V4>
  <LDA_CONFIG_T_V4>
    <CONFIG_ATTRB_VALUE>90</CONFIG_ATTRB_VALUE>
    <BOX_LABEL>
      <Value>   
        <TIEGROUP>1</TIEGROUP>
        <LABEL_TEMPLATE>LABEL_TEMPLATE</LABEL_TEMPLATE>
        <GTINTYPE>TEST GTINTYPE</GTINTYPE>
        <GTINVALUE>1</GTINVALUE>
        <MODELNUM>TEST MODELNUM</MODELNUM>
        <MODELDESCRIPTION>TEST MODELDESC</MODELDESCRIPTION>
        <COLOR>TEST Color</COLOR>
        <COUNTRY>TEST COUNTRY</COUNTRY>       
      </Value>        
    </BOX_LABEL>
    <TIEGROUP>1</TIEGROUP>
    <TIEGROUPIsNull>false</TIEGROUPIsNull>
    <CONFIG_ATTRB_NAME>LOB</CONFIG_ATTRB_NAME>
    <WO_ID>20015670070</WO_ID>
    <WO_IDIsNull>false</WO_IDIsNull>
    <WORK_ORDER_LINE_NO>1</WORK_ORDER_LINE_NO>
    <WORK_ORDER_LINE_NOIsNull>false</WORK_ORDER_LINE_NOIsNull>
    <SYSTEM_LABEL>
      <Value>
        <TIEGROUP>1</TIEGROUP>
        <LABEL_TEMPLATE>LABEL_TEMPLATE</LABEL_TEMPLATE>
        <GTINTYPE>TEST GTINTYPE</GTINTYPE>
        <GTINVALUE />
        <MODELNUM>TEST MODELNUM</MODELNUM>
        <MODELDESCRIPTION>TEST MODELDESC</MODELDESCRIPTION>
        <COLOR>TEST Color</COLOR>
        <COUNTRY>TEST COUNTRY</COUNTRY>           
      </Value>        
    </SYSTEM_LABEL>
    <SALES_ORDER_REF>10016041740</SALES_ORDER_REF>
    <SALES_ORDER_REFIsNull>false</SALES_ORDER_REFIsNull>
  </LDA_CONFIG_T_V4>
</Value>
</ldaConfigTblV4_0>
```

I want to get the `LDA_CONFIG_T_V4` nodes with distinct TIEGROUP, in this case I should get only first two `LDA_CONFIG_T_V4` node since the last node is having same TIEGROUP as the first one.

I tried it with the following XPath expression

```
ldaConfigTblV4_0/Value/LDA_CONFIG_T_V4[TIEGROUP[not(.=preceding::TIEGROUP)]]
```

but it is not working when I have multiple `LDA_CONFIG_T_V4` nodes, it works fine if I have single `LDA_CONFIG_T_V4` node. I tried with `ldaConfigTblV4_0/Value/LDA_CONFIG_T_V4[TIEGROUP[not(.=following::TIEGROUP)]]` this as well but of no use.

Comment: Please note, I'm using Xpath Version 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close. Your idea is correct, but your `not()` is at an incorrect location to achieve what you want.

```
ldaConfigTblV4_0/Value/LDA_CONFIG_T_V4[not(TIEGROUP = preceding::TIEGROUP)]
```

The following is a little bit more efficient (using `prececing-sibling` instead of `preceding` leads to fewer nodes checked:

```
ldaConfigTblV4_0/Value/LDA_CONFIG_T_V4[not(TIEGROUP = preceding-sibling::LDA_CONFIG_T_V4/TIEGROUP)]
```

Comment: ldaConfigTblV4_0/Value/LDA_CONFIG_T_V4[not(TIEGROUP=preceding-sibling::LDA_CONFIG_T_V4/TIEGROUP)]